# pdf.js and viewer.html Default zoom initial value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf.js

js

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/

I´m calling in this way http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx./pdf/web/viewer.html?file=file.pdf

Now the question is how can I set the value to 75% default zoom like initial value display?

Comment: What is 'initial value display'? Also which value are you trying to set?

Comment: The initial value is page-fit but I want at 75%

Comment: Please reference the value you're trying to set, the context in which it exists is important to the way you'd set it.

Comment: I want to modify the viewer.html or viewer.js but honestly I don´t know there is controlled that features. The default value afer unzip the pdf.js-master.zip is auto I just want to change that value for 75% that´s it.

Comment: I think your problem isn't not knowing *how* to set the value, rather what value to set.

Comment: See https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Viewer-options

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for?

`/pdf/web/viewer.html#zoom=75`

working example

http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html#zoom=75

Comment: Just simply like that that is wanted to do. Thank you Remi

Answer (score 0):

In web/viewer.js line 109

```
Change var DEFAULT_SCALE_VALUE = 'auto';
to var DEFAULT_SCALE_VALUE = 'page-width';
```

it works well.

source: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/9583